# Kafka performance with stored data

Tags: apache-kafka

From my reading, whenever a Producer writes a message to a Topic, that message is written to disk.

This is done via the OS through use of the pagecache (so the message is actually written to the pagecahce first and then to disk, all handled by the OS).
This means that, provided the Producer and Consumer and running in parallel, you are able to achieve good speeds because when the Consumer gets the message from the Topic, it is coming directly from the pagecache.
However, should the Consumer either fall behind in reading messages (unable to consume them as fast as they are being produced) or should the Consumer go offline for a period of time, when it would have to start consuming messages from disk instead of the pagecache. Would this not result in a much slower experience for the Consumer?

The reason I am asking is because in this article about Kafka Benchmarking (https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) there is a section called “Producer Throughput Versus Stored Data” and it states:

“One of the hidden dangers of many messaging systems is that they work well only as long as the data they retain fits in memory. Their throughput falls by an order of magnitude (or more) when data backs up and isn't consumed (and hence needs to be stored on disk). This means things may be running fine as long as your consumers keep up and the queue is empty, but as soon as they lag, the whole messaging layer backs up with unconsumed data. The backup causes data to go to disk which in turns causes performance to drop to a rate that means messaging system can no longer keep up with incoming data and either backs up or falls over. This is pretty terrible, as in many cases the whole purpose of the queue was to handle such a case gracefully.
Since Kafka always persists messages the performance is O(1) with respect to unconsumed data volume.”

I do not understand the last section:
“Since Kafka always persists messages the performance is O(1) with respect to unconsumed data volume.”

Since if what I understand about Kafka writing to disk via the pagecache is correct, then surely Kafka suffers from the same issue of some messages having to be Consumed from disk?

Comment: Keep in mind, If your consumer reads recent messages, i.e. keeps up with producer, then speed of reading is limited by speed of message appearance on the broker, i.e. speed of writing to disk. Even if a consumer reads from a pagecache, a broker handles a stream of producing messages not faster then they are written.  If you consume "old" stored messages, then speed is limited by reading from disk. So, anyway, consuming speed is limited by disk throughput, either write or read.

Comment: So the producer sends a message to the Broker (Topic) and the message is read into the Broker machines pagecache. The Consumer then reads the message out of the pagecache before the OS has the opportunity to write the message to disk. After the message has been consumed the Broker/OS writes the message to disk. Or are you saying that a Broker is never aware of a message until is has been written from the pagecache to disk, and therefore cannot be consumed before it has been written to disk?

Comment: I got your question, and as I see it doesn't matter. Either broker aware of a message before it's written, or not, a broker couldn't consume message stream at a higher rate that it is written. Otherwise, where would incoming messages be stored, in the RAM until it will be over? So I conclude reading from pagecache could affect latency (from producer to consumer), but not throughput. Since all the upcoming messages are finally stored at a disk, they couldn't be consumed by broker at a higher rate, then it takes to process the stream, which eventually but necessarily involves writing to disk.